# Question on rank of matrices over $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, enumerative-combinatorics

$A$ is a square matrix in $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ of rank $k\leq n-1$.

$B$ is a square matrix in $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ of rank $n$.

$T$ is a square matrix in $\mathbb F_2^{n\times n}$ of rank $1$.

1. Is there conditions under which $A+T$ is full rank? $k=n-1$ is necessary.
2. Is there conditions under which $B+T$ is rank $<n$ (rank becomes $n-1$)?

Comment: And what is $F_2$? The two-element group? If so, say so.

Comment: Finite field in two elements.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @WillSawin It is no hw. $T$ seemed to be any monochromatic matrix (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382945/on-a-k-l-monochromatic-hamming-distance-in-mathbb-f-2). I cannot possibly confirm if there can or cannot be any combinatorial condition. The problem came up while trying for smaller uniform circuits for Det mod 2. I think there are no easy conditions which will simplify Det mod 2 computation even if we assume a permutation as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382957/schur-complement-and-depermuting-an-algorithm-for-determinant-modulo-2 is provided as input.

Comment: @willsawin I think determinant modulo $2$ is in $\mathsf{NC}^1$ (it is not believed to be so and determinant modulo $2$ is $\oplus L$ complete which is in $\mathsf{NC}^2$).

Comment: $B+T$ has rank $<n$ if and only if $I+ B^{-1}T$ has rank $<n$ which happens if and only if $B^{-1}T$ has eigenvalue $1$ which happens if and only if $B^{-1}T$ has trace $1$. So solving this problem, even in the special case where $T$ has one entry nonzero, is basically equivalent to calculating the inverse of $B$.

Comment: @WillSawin Perhaps there is another route to $\mathsf{NC}^1$.